# Cannot cast integer as byte

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am attempting to pull an integer from a configuration file using the Bukkit Minecraft api. I don't really understand why exactly I must use a byte (never really learned about them as of yet) and am getting the following error when using code that seems to be working for others :

Cannot cast from Integer to byte.

```
player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(dItemId1), 1, (byte) dItemMeta1));
```

dItemMeta1 is simply a variable pulled from a config file and defined as follows :

```
public Integer dItemMeta1;
dItemMeta1 = getConfig().getInt("FirstDonationItemIdMeta");
```

Could anyone please enlighten me on the way to properly utilize this or perhaps how to properly define it as a byte in the first place when taking the value from the config?

Comment: You are trying to cast an object to a primitive type. Use [Integer.byteValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#byteValue%28%29) instead.

Comment: better you should use **public int dItemMeta1**

Comment: (byte)(int)dItemMeta1 should work. Also dItemMeta1.byteValue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an `Integer` object into an `int` primitive or cast an `int` into a `byte` but you can't cast all the way from `Integer` to `byte` (A step too far for the Java designers)

What you can do is

```
player.getInventory().removeItem(new ItemStack(
         Material.getMaterial(dItemId1), 1, dItemMeta1.byteValue()));
```

Note: this will throw a NullPointerException if dItemMeta1 is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your variable `dItemMeta1` is of type Integer (not int), and conversion from Integer to byte is not a direct step but it will take place as, `Integer->int->byte`

You can use function [byteValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#byteValue%28%29), and write `dItemMeta1.byteValue()`, to return byte directly from Integer.